# Verify a row in one table matches a row in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on an archiving project right now which involves moving data out of tables in one database to tables in an archive database.  The process goes as follows:

1. Find a record you want to archive
2. Verify it isn't already archived
3. Copy the data over
4. Verify all the data is copied over
5. Delete the data from the source

I'm looking for how to do step 4.  I want to make sure that every value in a column in a given row in my archive table is exactly the same as every value in a column in a given row in my production table.  I just want to do this so I know it will be safe to delete the data out of the production table.  The tables that i'm working with both have identical columns.  Right now, I'm simply checking to see if the Id of row in production exists in the archive before I delete it.  I know I can do a lot better, but I'm not a true expert on SQL.  The solution I can think of that falls within my current knowledge would be long and painful, so I'm seeing if there's a quick, one query way of doing this.

This is pseudocode and I'm mixing my C# with this, but I need something like:

```
(SELECT * FROM [Production].[dbo].[Table1] WHERE Id = '1234') == (SELECT * FROM [Archive].[dbo].[Table1] WHERE Id = '1234')
```

And yes, I'm well aware that isn't correct syntax ;)

Comment: `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Archive WHERE [...] EXCEPT SELECT * FROM Production WHERE [...])` verifies all `Archive` rows exist in `Production` (checking the other side is left as an exercise). It's probable all the steps you describe ought to be done in a more set-based manner, possibly using `MERGE`.

Comment: The problem with EXCEPT is (I think) both tables need the same number of rows.  In my scenario, there will most certainly never be the same number in either.

Comment: `EXCEPT` takes all rows from the first table and removes all rows from the second table that match. If any remain, then `Archive` contains rows that aren't in `Production`. (This is probably expected since `Archive` contains older stuff, but that's what the `WHERE` is for.) Admittedly you probably want the other way around ("are there any rows in `Production` that aren't in `Archive`?") There's also `INTERSECT` and `UNION` -- SQL has a full complement of set operators. An exact 1-to-1 relation is never required (not even for `JOIN`), and in fact you need to check for it if it's desired.

Comment: @user1059903 can you tell us a bit more about your tables? I notice you are filtering on ID in your query; is ID unique to a record?

Comment: @EdwardRusu Yes, the Id is unique to a record, but not unique between tables.  The idea is that they are an exact match.

Comment: @user1059903 How are you enforcing that the ID's are unique to each record in the Archive table? Suppose you are at Step 3 with records in Archive whose ID's are like {4802, 4803, 4804, ...}. Furthermore, suppose you have records in the Production table with the same ID's, but by Step 2 you have verified that they aren't already archived (this is possible because you said the ID's are not unique between tables). When you add these new records into Archive, what do you do to their ID's to ensure ID's are unique in the Archive table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Sample Data:

```
DECLARE @Archive AS TABLE (id varchar(1), other varchar(1), another varchar(2), yetanother varchar(2))
DECLARE @Production AS TABLE (id varchar(1), other varchar(1), another varchar(2))

INSERT INTO @Production  VALUES('1','1','11')
INSERT INTO @Production  VALUES('2','2','22')
INSERT INTO @Archive VALUES('1','1','11','11')
INSERT INTO @Archive VALUES('3','3','33','33')
```

Query:

```
DECLARE @id INT = 1

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(SELECT id, other, another FROM @Production WHERE Id = @id
EXCEPT
SELECT id, other, another FROM @Archive WHERE Id = @id) AS x
```

0 indicates no match!

Using your exact example you would have:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(SELECT id, col1, col2, etc... FROM [Production].[dbo].[Table1] WHERE Id = '1234'
EXCEPT
SELECT id, col1, col2, etc... FROM [Archive].[dbo].[Table1] WHERE Id = '1234') AS x
```

More info on EXCEPT [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)

Comment: That won't work because the number of rows in production does not match the archive.  I'm simply looking to see if a single given record in production matches a single given record in the archive.

Comment: This is just checking one record in each table, I've moved the variable from the sample data to make this more obvious.

Comment: I get this when I run that:

    All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: You need to specify what columns rather than SELECT * they must have a different number of columns. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Ah, ok, gotcha.  That will end up being a lot more work to do than I wanted, but it might be the only way this will work.  By the way, I think you'd want to use INTERSECT instead of EXCEPT in that example.  My hope is that they DO match so I can safely delete one of them.  In that example, using an INTERSECT when selecting two columns with a matching Id gave me a 1.  I then changed the Id of one of the select statements knowing full well that they wouldn't match and it gave me a 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the following query you can compare manually;

```
SELECT * FROM [Production].[dbo].[Table1] pt
FULL OUTER JOIN [Archive].[dbo].[Table1] at ON pt.id=at.id
```

Depending what fields you have you can do;

```
SELECT * FROM [Production].[dbo].[Table1] pt
FULL OUTER JOIN [Archive].[dbo].[Table1] at ON pt.id=at.id
WHERE pt.Column1 <> at.Column1 OR pt.Column2 <> at.Column2..etc
```

To get only the differences

Comment: That works in a sense, yes, but I'm not looking for a "manual" process if I can avoid it.  If it's possible to just get a yes or no / true or false answer, that would be the best.